# C# Word Interop Cut/Paste Image from one Doc to another Doc

Tags: c#, image, ms-word

C# using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

I'm trying to:

- Locate the first image in a document
- Cut the image.
- Open a 2nd document
- Locate its first image
- Delete that image
- Paste the original image in its place

Right Now the program only cuts the image from Doc1, - then nothing else happens until it saves both files. No errors. What am I missing here?

---

```
string filePath1 = "...";
string filePath2 = "...";

object missing = System.Type.Missing;
_Application app = new Application();
app.Visible = false;

//Open the Source Document
Document doc1 = app.Documents.Open(filePath1);

//Locate the First Image
InlineShape img = null;
foreach (InlineShape shape in doc1.InlineShapes) 
{ 
    if (img == null && shape.Type == WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
          img = shape;
}


 //Open the 2nd Document (Doc2)
 Document doc2 = app.Documents.Open(filePath2);


//If we found the image then 
if (img != null)
{
    //Cut the Image
    img.Range.Cut();

    

    bool t = false;

    //Find the First Picture in Doc2
    foreach (InlineShape shape2 in doc2.InlineShapes)
    {
       if (!t && shape2.Type == WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture) 
       {
            //Delete the image from the 2nd Document
            shape2.Delete();
            
            //In it's place, Paste the Image from Doc1 into Doc2
            doc2.Range().Paste();
            t = true; 
       }
    }
}

doc1.SaveAs(filePath1);
doc1.Close();

doc2.SaveAs(filePath2);
doc2.Close();

app.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```

Comment: Is the `foreach` actually being run? (also you could bail out by using `break;` instead of `t = true;`)

Comment: @Charlieface noted. When I debug, the code jumps from `img.Range.Cut()` straight to File Saving. I'm not sure why it doesn't even check for shapes inside Doc2 because they are clearly there.

Comment: Alright - So I found out that Doc2 does not have any `InlineShapes` but rather has `Shapes`. Doc2 is a static doc so I tried to figure out which `Shape` the image was at. I did a foreach loop on the Shapes and deleted each one, but the image never deleted! How can the image exist in the Document and not be a Shape?